# how to get file modified date in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am a developer who is new to sharepoint . Can you please kindly tell me how to get the file modified date in sharepoint 2007 via sharepoint web service 
?

I know that sharepoint client is only for sharepoint 2010 and 2013. I have tried system.io last modified date which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/drjohn/archive/2007/11/02/Getting-a-list-of-files-from-a-moss-document-library-using-a-SharePoint-web-service.aspx) example has what you need.

Here's the code contained within it in case something happens to the link:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text;

using System.Xml;

using System.Web.Services;

using System.Web;

using System.Net;



namespace ConsoleApplication1

{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

string siteUrl = @"http://yourserver/sites/yoursite";

string documentLibraryName = @"Shared Documents";


SharePointList.Lists wsList = new SharePointList.Lists();

wsList.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

WebProxy proxyObj = new WebProxy("yourproxy", 80);

wsList.Proxy = proxyObj;

wsList.Url = siteUrl + @"/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";



// get a list of all top level lists

XmlNode allLists = wsList.GetListCollection();

// load into an XML document so we can use XPath to query content

XmlDocument allListsDoc = new XmlDocument();

allListsDoc.LoadXml(allLists.OuterXml);

// allListsDoc.Save(@"c:\allListsDoc.xml"); // for debug

XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(allListsDoc.NameTable);

ns.AddNamespace("d", allLists.NamespaceURI);



// now get the GUID of the document library we are looking for

XmlNode dlNode = allListsDoc.SelectSingleNode("/d:Lists/d:List[@Title='" + documentLibraryName + "']", ns);

if (dlNode == null)

{

Console.WriteLine("Document Library '{0}' not found!", documentLibraryName);

}

else

{

// obtain the GUID for the document library and the webID

string documentLibraryGUID = dlNode.Attributes["ID"].Value;

string webId = dlNode.Attributes["WebId"].Value;



Console.WriteLine("Opening folder '{0}' GUID={1}", documentLibraryName, documentLibraryGUID);



// create ViewFields CAML

XmlDocument viewFieldsDoc = new XmlDocument();

XmlNode ViewFields = AddXmlElement(viewFieldsDoc, "ViewFields", "");

AddFieldRef(ViewFields, "GUID");

AddFieldRef(ViewFields, "ContentType");

AddFieldRef(ViewFields, "BaseName");

AddFieldRef(ViewFields, "Modified");

AddFieldRef(ViewFields, "EncodedAbsUrl");

//viewFieldsDoc.Save(@"c:\viewFields.xml"); // for debug



// create QueryOptions CAML

XmlDocument queryOptionsDoc = new XmlDocument();

XmlNode QueryOptions = AddXmlElement(queryOptionsDoc, "QueryOptions", "");

AddXmlElement(QueryOptions, "Folder", documentLibraryName);

AddXmlElement(QueryOptions, "IncludeMandatoryColumns", "FALSE");

// this element is the key to getting the full recusive list

XmlNode node = AddXmlElement(QueryOptions, "ViewAttributes", "");

AddXmlAttribute(node, "Scope", "Recursive");

queryOptionsDoc.Save(@"c:\queryOptions.xml"); // for debug



// obtain the list of items in the document library

XmlNode listContent = wsList.GetListItems(documentLibraryGUID, null, null, ViewFields, null, QueryOptions, webId);



XmlDocument xmlResultsDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlResultsDoc.LoadXml(listContent.OuterXml);

ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlResultsDoc.NameTable);

ns.AddNamespace("z", "#RowsetSchema");

// xmlResultsDoc.Save(@"c:\listContent.xml"); // for debug



XmlNodeList rows = xmlResultsDoc.SelectNodes("//z:row", ns);

if (rows.Count == 0)

{

Console.WriteLine("No content found");

}

foreach (XmlNode row in rows)

{

Console.WriteLine(row.Attributes["ows_ContentType"].Value + " " + row.Attributes["ows_GUID"].Value + " :: " + row.Attributes["ows_BaseName"].Value);

}

}

Console.WriteLine("Done");

Console.Read();

}



public static XmlNode AddXmlElement(XmlNode parent, string elementName, string elementValue)

{

XmlNode element = parent.AppendChild(parent.OwnerDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, elementName, ""));

if (elementValue != "")

element.InnerText = elementValue;

return (element);

}



public static XmlNode AddXmlElement(XmlDocument parent, string elementName, string elementValue)

{

XmlNode element = parent.AppendChild(parent.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, elementName, ""));

if (elementValue != "")

element.InnerText = elementValue;

return (element);

}



public static XmlNode AddXmlAttribute(XmlNode element, string attrName, string attrValue)

{

XmlNode attr = element.Attributes.Append((XmlAttribute)element.OwnerDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Attribute, attrName, ""));

if (attrValue != "")

attr.Value = attrValue;

return (attr);

}



public static void AddFieldRef(XmlNode viewFields, string fieldName)

{

    XmlNode fieldRef = AddXmlElement(viewFields, "FieldRef", "");

    AddXmlAttribute(fieldRef, "Name", fieldName);

}

}

}
```